# hypothesis testing in hierarchical trees

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, dendrogram

Suppose I have an hierarchical tree organising people according to their music preferences. Each person then has 3 extra properties A, B and C (e.g. parent's supportiveness on musical education).

I wanted to select people from A and test across several tree distances if their friends tend to be more A or C then the friends from group B. The goal of the toy example is to find distant influences in friend's space (tree) between music preferences and parent's supportiveness on musical education not just of person in question but also of the friends.

I was wondering if a Pearson's chi-square test would be appropriate in this scenario. As I see it, there are two cohorts:

Cohort1: people from group A.
Cohort2: people from group B.

Then, for a given tree distance (dist=2,3,4 ... ), test wether cohort1 friends are A or not A more than cohort2.

Possible problems: The different cohorts are composed of different people (A!=B) but at a given tree distance cohort1 and cohort2 will have friend's in common (e.g., at distance 4 across tree branches, a friend from group A of a person34 from group A, cohort1, can also be a friend of person38 from group B- cohort2). Does this mean independency between rows of my contingency table does not hold?

Thanks!